# change background color of list using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've a list. i'm adding data in it through ajax. i want to change the background of selected list item . 
here is my list

```
 <div class="widget-content" >
                <ul class="news-items" id='jq_friendList'>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

i'm adding the list list item using ajax, like this

```
function getFriends()
{
    var lines = '<img src="img/loader.gif" height="45" width="45" />';

    document.getElementById('jq_friendList').innerHTML=lines;

   var strURL="./MainActivity.php";
   var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
   if (req)
   {
     req.onreadystatechange = function()
     {
      if (req.readyState == 4)
      {
     // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200)
         {          
         var myDiVElem = document.getElementById('jq_friendList');
                myDiVElem.innerHTML="";
        myDiVElem.innerHTML=req.responseText;
     } else {

     }
       }
      }
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send();
   }    
}
```

i have used jquery to change the selected background like this , but this is changing the whole ul background .

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
$("#jq_friendList").live('click',function()
{
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For highlighting the selected **list item** try

```
$("#jq_friendList").on('click','li',function() {
 $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

other answers seems to be highlighting the whole `<ul>`

**Update**

for resetting  the previously highlighted item, use a css class

```
.highlight{
background:blue;
}
```

and try

```
$("#jq_friendList").on('click','li',function() {
 $('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
 $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: this is working . but sir , when i click on other list item , then the  background of previous list-item should be as of original.

Comment: @PiTheNumber yes, you updated your non-working answer with my answer few minutes ago, which is clearly visible in your answers edit history.. :)

Comment: @TJ I actually had that myself in jsfiddle before I did see yours just got the question wrong the first time. But well, I don't care ;)

Comment: Using a class for this is nice! @OP Also note that there is a `toogleClass()` that comes in handy sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Do like  this, for before **jquery 1.7**:

```
$("#jq_friendList li").live('click',function()
{
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

and above **jquery 1.7**:

```
$("#jq_friendList").on('click','li',function()
    {
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
    });
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jms86/) [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jms86/)

Comment: it will change the background of whole "ul". i just want to change single "li".

Comment: @AmitKumar check now.

Comment: this is working . but sir , when i click on other list item , then the background of previous list-item should be as of original.

Answer (score 1):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#jq_friendList").on('click','li',function() {
    $(this).parent().find('li').css("background-color", "");
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dwcUQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

```
$("#jq_friendList li").on('click',function()
{
    $("#jq_friendList li").css("background-color", "red") // other li color provided instead of red 
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue"); // active li

});
```

Comment: Can't you see that sees info is already given in other answers??

Comment: Sorry i didn't see Milind answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here by utilizing **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** since your element has been added dynamically to the DOM:

```
$("body").on('click','#jq_friendList',function() {
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

Comment: not working.
i just want , suppose there is 5 list item, when i click one any of list item , then the background of that particular list item should be  blue.

Answer (score 0):

`.live()` is deprectaed in jquery 1.7+. use `.on()` instead:

```
$(".news-items").on('click',function()
{
    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
});
```